# Regular expression parsing multiple text on condition

Tags: regex, perl

String mentioned below

```perl
$string1 = "Job Description : Advt.No.01/2019-FCI Category IIIJunior Engineer /Assistant recruitment in Food Corporation of India (FCI) FCI recruiting 4103 Vacancies f...";
$string2 = "Job Description : Assistant Professor (Management) job recruitment in Saurashtra University on contract basis No. of Post : 01 Eligibility :  As per ...";
```

The above string may be one at a time in text

1. case: I need to parse no of post or vacancies numeric value. suppose if i find vacancies keyword then i need to get numeric value close to vacancies.
2. case: suppose if now vacancies is not found in string then again i need to perform search on No. of Post and find numeric value close to it.

So, how may I write the regular expression for it. I have two regular expression

```perl
$string2 =~ m/(?:pos.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+/ig;
print $1;

$string1 =~ m/(\d+)\s+(?:vac.*?)/ig;
print $2;
```

I need to write one regular expression to work in both case. So, how may I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
/(\d+ vacancies|no\. of post \: \d+)/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is certainly possible to squeeze it into one unreadable regular expression conglomerate, divide and conquer might be the better strategy. My solution presents two possible alternatives.

You can of course relax or tighten the regexes based on your real-life input.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string1 = "Job Description : Advt.No.01/2019-FCI Category IIIJunior Engineer /Assistant recruitment in Food Corporation of India (FCI) FCI recruiting 4103 Vacancies f...";
my $string2 = "Job Description : Assistant Professor (Management) job recruitment in Saurashtra University on contract basis No. of Post : 01 Eligibility :  As per ...";

# alternative 1
foreach my $string ($string1, $string2) {
    $string =~ /(\d+)\s+vacancies/i    ||
    $string =~ /no\. of post : (\d+)/i
        or die "no match for '${string}'\n";
    print "MATCH: $1\n";
}

# alternative 2
foreach my $string ($string1, $string2) {
    my($submatch) = $string =~ /(\d+\s+vacancies|no\. of post : \d+)/i
        or die "no match for '${string}'\n";
    my($number) = $submatch =~ /(\d+)/;
    print "MATCH: ${number}\n";
}


exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
MATCH: 4103
MATCH: 01
MATCH: 4103
MATCH: 01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, I combined both your regex with `|` and used `(?| )` to get the all matches in `$1`

```
$string=~m/(?|(?:pos.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+|(\d+)\s+(?:vac.*?))/ig;
print $1,"\n";
```